# Flutter-Firestore: Update Multiple Docs At Once

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am pretty new to Flutter and I have spent some time on this and cannot find a clear answer for what I am trying to do. I am querying a collection for a couple of docs and then trying to update them using the `batch` function. However, I am having trouble understanding the documentation and previous answers on how exactly to use the `batch` function in Flutter with Firestore with multiple docs. The query seems to be working and returning the docs, but the `batch.update()` is throwing an error that I cannot figure out how to solve. Here is what I have

```
InkWell(
 onTap: () async {
  final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
  var pushNotifications = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('collection name')
    .where(first filter)
    .where(second filter)
    .get();
print(pushNotifications.docs.length);
//this is where the error is occuring when trying to update the batch
  for (var postDocs in pushNotificiations.docs) {
     batch.update(postDocs.reference, {
     "user_refs" : usersInchallenge
   }
   );
await batch.commit();
)
```

UPDATE: I am getting closer but now it is only updating the first document of the batch and not the rest. It is giving the error below with the udpated code snippet.

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: This batch has already been committed and can no longer be changed.
```

Answer (score 1):

After banging my head against a wall for a few hours, here is what finally worked with `batch()` after querying multiple docs.

```
final batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
var pushNotificiations = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('ff_user_push_notifications')
  .where(filter 1)
  .where(filter 2)
  .get();

print(pushNotificiations.docs.length);

pushNotificiations.docs.forEach((doc) => {
batch.update(doc.reference, {
"user_refs" : usersInchallenge
  }),
});

batch.commit();
```